# Copy theme from another application

Tags: android, android-context, android-theme

I have an application that contains a custom theme and I wish to share it with other applications. The idea is that this application provides themes to other applications.

The theme is defined in styles.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

<style name="Text">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#FFFF9200</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#FFCCFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">#5C5CFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>

<style name="Button">
    <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFF00</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">22dip</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.example" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/Text</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

To get this theme from the second app:

```
Context appThemesContext = this.getApplicationContext().  
                           createPackageContext("com.appThemes", 
                                                 Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
appThemesContext.setTheme(0x7f050002); //The resid of the desired theme
this.getTheme().setTo(appThemesContext.getTheme()); //Copy the theme
```

The problem is that only the direct attributes like "background" are copied, the references attributes like "buttonStyle" not, because the "setTo" method says:

> Set this theme to hold the same contents as the theme other. If both of these themes are from the same Resources object, they will be identical after this function returns. If they are from different Resources, only the resources they have in common will be set in this theme.

Does anyone know how to copy a theme from the resources of other application?? The theme won't use resources like images, etc... only values.

Thanks ;)

Comment: I made some test, and it is for me impossible to re-use the theme of another app correctly. So I think you can re-use this theme in the other app.

Comment: Maybe the apps must have the same user id. I can reuse the theme, but only the direct values are copied, the references styles not.

Comment: No changes for me with the same userID.

Comment: Any updates on this? I keep getting ResourceNotFound exceptions.

Comment: I gave up, after many tries (and many days) i think that it's impossible to copy a whole theme from other Context, cause there's no way to access to the attributes that are references (and not values), because they are in other Context. Finally, I'm using a shared library that contains all the styles that the other apps may use.

Comment: did you tried http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getResourcesForApplication%28java.lang.String%29 ?

Comment: Yes I did, but I was unable to use it for load the theme.